# Identify YA novel from 70's/80's with three psychic youths stranded on primitive planet

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, psychic

I remember reading a book I checked out from my local library in the late 70's or early 80's, and I'm trying to find the name (and hopefully a copy I can read again). The novel featured three young people (or possibly two young people, guy and girl, and and older man), all of whom had some psychic powers, who get stranded on a somewhat backwater planet and are trying to leave. In one scene, I remember them attending a circus or traveling carnival, and being worried about tipping their hands about being able to read minds. And I remember in the climax, one of the characters sacrifices himself to enable the other two to get away (though he does climb into some kind of "auto doc" and it may have been vague about whether he would pull through in the end).

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["The Galactic Rejects"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1574978.The_Galactic_Rejects), Andrew J. Offut, 1967.

> Stranded on an unknown planet, two men and a girl from Earth devise a carnival act to disguise their special powers and better fit in with the natives.

Yes, the man was older and the boy and girl were teens.  The man could read minds; the girl had telekenesis, and the boy could teleport. Ends with the the teleporter being shot with poison darts, pressing the spacecraft release button so the other two could escape the planet, and collapsing to die. I do not recall any autodoc.

Comment: OK, I bought another copy and read the book. There is discussion of the *existence* of "Doctors", i.e. autodocs, but there was none nearby when the boy died.